# Geth import a local backup slower than syncing

Tags: go-ethereum, import, backup

System: Linux, SSD, 64G RAM

Is there a way to speed up the process of importing a local Backup?

So I run a node for a while (completly synced until yesterday) and wanted to play around a bit more.

I did a full backup with:

```
geth --datadir /my/local/path/to/blockchain export /my/local/path/to/Backup/folder/Block0-15M3
```

Played around a bit made some misstakes, deleted the whole chain with

```
geth removedb
```

uninstalled geth and dependencies, cleaned everything that has to do with geth. Only my backup still exists.- Installed geth and dependencies again

Run geth with nodiscover, so all the folderstructure and so on get built again in the "Blockchain" directory.

```
geth console --datadir /my/local/path/to/blockchain --nodiscover

exit
```

Importing my backup (so I dont have to download / syncing from / with other nodes)

```
geth --datadir /my/local/path/to/blockchain import /my/local/path/to/Backup/folder/Block0-15M3
```

The import is running now for 5 hours (export was ~2:30h) 21 / 635 GiB done so far and is slower than if I would go and sync with other nodes.

Is there a way to speed that process up? For sure it will not be the last time I have to do this because I mess something up.

Thanks for any help.